# Java - Why is my Bubble Sort faster than my Insertion Sort?

Tags: java, sorting

I'm measuring the number of steps it takes for sorts to complete sorting and for whatever reason, bubble sort always seems to be a tad quicker than insertion sort and from what I read, it should be the other way around.

Not going to post my full code, but I believe the issue may lie with where I have my counts.

**Bubble sort:**

```
public void sort()
{
    for (out = nElems-1 ; out >= 1 ; out--)
    {
        count = count+1;
        for (in = 0 ; in < out ; in++)
        {
            if ((a.get(in)) > (a.get(in+1)))
            {
                swap (in, in+1);
                count = count+2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Insertion Sort:**

```
void sort()
{
    Integer temp[] = new Integer[1];
    for (out = 1 ; out < nElems ; out++)
    {
        count = count+1;
        temp[0] = a.get(out);
        in = out;
        while (in > 0 && a.get(in-1) >= temp[0])
        {
            a.set(in, a.get(in-1));
            --in;
            count = count+2;
        }
        a.set(in, temp[0]);
    }
}
```

and just to give an example, I sorted 3 text files filled with 2000 random integers with values from 1-2000, the average for insertion sort was 2,007,677 steps, and bubble sort's average was 2,005,719.

Comment: How do you count steps? Shouldn't you be counting the number of comparisons being made? Or maybe the number of accesses to the array (read or write)?

Comment: Yeah, you're missing comparisons in bubble sort (the innermost if, the inner loop continuation condition). And that's just two things, I haven't even looked at insertion sort.

Comment: If you have count=count+2 for the swap, shouldn't you just have count=count+1 for the one-way transfer?

Comment: @Thilo Sorry, that's what I meant by steps. For a file of 2000 integers, best case being 2000 and worst case being 4 million (2000^2). For both sorts.

Comment: Okay, so this is just confusing me more. Sorry guys, I'm a newbie at this stuff. So when you guys are talking about comparisons, are you talking about compareTo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, you're only measuring assignments, not overall performance.  Secondly, your insertion sort has the optimization of not swapping to move the value over, so why are you adding 2 to `count` every time?  Your while loop should only be adding 1 to `count`, and then you should add 1 again outside the while loop when you have the `a.set(in,temp[0])`.  (Side note - why is `temp` an array and not just a single Integer?)
Now, if you want to measure overall performance, you need to measure comparisons and assignments (preferably in two separate variables, as certain devices/architectures can have very different performance for those operations).

Edit:

To clarify, a comparison is when you compare the values of two items from your array with an operator like less than (<) or greater than (>).  An assignment is when you change a value within an array (in your case, using `a.set()`).

Here's some code modifications (I split `count` into two variables that represent the actual things you'll want to measure, `assignments` and `comparisons`):

Bubble sort:

```
public void sort()
{
    for (out = nElems-1 ; out >= 1 ; out--)
    {
        for (in = 0 ; in < out ; in++)
        {
            comparisons = comparisons+1;
            if ((a.get(in)) > (a.get(in+1)))
            {
                swap (in, in+1);
                assignments = assignments+2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Insertion sort:

```
void sort()
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (out = 1 ; out < nElems ; out++)
    {
        count = count+1;
        temp[0] = a.get(out);
        in = out;
        comparisons = comparisons + 1; //You're doing the comparison below at least once
        while (in > 0 && a.get(in-1) >= temp[0])
        {
            a.set(in, a.get(in-1));
            --in;
            assignments = assignments+1;
            comparisons = comparisons + 1; 
        }
        a.set(in, temp[0]);
        assignments = assignments+1;
    }
}
```

One other thing to consider - where are you initializing the variable `count`?  I don't see it in your code, and it could actually be that you're using the same variable from a different scope, and since you don't reset it to 0, whichever sort you're doing second is adding onto the number from your first one.

Comment: Adding 2 every time because it was what worked for the correct Best/Worst Case Scenarios (believe me, I tried the +1 to begin with). Best case being 2000, worst being 2000^2. I have the +1 added to the outside of my while loop already. As for the temp as an array, it was a choice by my professor, so I just decided to follow the example.

Comment: Well, adding 2 is correct if you don't do the optimization of shifting and then inserting the value once you find the right spot - perhaps your sample best/worst case were meant to be without that optimization?

Comment: Instead of an edit, since I see you put some work in. I'm working with bigO, so I'm a bit confused on whether I'm supposed to be measuring assignments, comparisons, or both (I assume both). I know that in my case, if I have a file with 2000 integers from 1-2000, sorting and already sorted file would give me a result of 2000 in both cases, and a result of 2000^2 in the worst case scenario. Your revision seems to give me some odd results.

Comment: The sorts are in their own classes by the way, each has a count set at 1 at the beginning of the class, so after each sort is completed it gets reset to 1.

Comment: I'd recommend clarifying with the teacher what you're supposed to measure, because that will definitely affect your measurements.  As for the value of 2000^2, I'm not sure which algorithm you mean to be using, or what you mean to measure, but I'll try my best:

If you mean insertion sort, then then for every item (which starts at current index of i), you insert it (doing i assignments) into the first position.  This means you have the sum of 1+2+3+...+1999.  This is on the order of n^2 (see summation formulas), but it's not equal to n^2 exactly.

Comment: Also, as a former graduate assistant and teacher of labs for this very subject, I can also tell you that you may have to consider that your teacher is fallible - on my school's version of this lab, our teacher's 'correct' values were based on making an optimization that he never discussed with the students, so they always got 'wrong' values.

Comment: At first I thought I was supposed to be measuring the effectiveness in time, and when I clarified this with her the other day I found out that it was supposed to be a count. We're doing BigO, so I know my values should have to do with the time complexity there. I've been using http://bigocheatsheet.com to help me figure out the values I should be getting and even sorting random values, I get a result of about 2million each time, which seems to be correct, but I don't know why my bubble sort < my insertion sort. Doesn't help that I was deathly ill the past week and a half, so I missed class.

Comment: Okay, some things that might be messing things up - I just realize I have an error - I missed one of the instances of  `count` for switching it to `assignments`.  Secondly, assigning to a temporary variable may or may not be considered an assignment, because it's not assigning within the array itself, so some people consider it to be trivial.  I'm going to write up some code, run it, and get back to you.

Comment: Here's a pastebin with pastebin links for my full code, it should be a lot easier to test with my full code (and not having to write up something new). Generate test data through DataGen: http://pastebin.com/GUPRiJme  - by the way, I caught where you missed count, so I wasn't worried about that. When I was testing it, and it was supposed to give back a value of 2000, it gave me a crazy number like 190,910 or something like that.

Comment: Okay, so I only now noticed your pastebin, and I already finished, so I'll just show you what I did: http://pastebin.com/CeG4NsLu.  Running it generates this:
Sorted, Insertion sort:
  Comparisons: 1999
  Assignments: 1999
Sorted, Bubble sort:
  Comparisons: 1999000
  Assignments: 0
Reverse sorted, Insertion sort:
  Comparisons: 2000999
  Assignments: 2000999
Reverse sorted, Bubble sort:
  Comparisons: 1999000
  Assignments: 3998000

Comment: It's close (in some cases) but still off. Insertion Sort, for Ascending order, I'd need to use either Comparisons or Assignments, but not both, Bubble sort should only be ~2000, not 2million. Descending order, adding the Comparisons and Assignments gives me close to the correct number of 4 million, and the assignments for bubble sort seems to be about right, or at least in the ball park. Random sorts should be ~2 million, which is what I originally had, but my numbers seem to be swapped ~+-2000. I really do appreciate the help though and it gives me a new perspective.

Comment: Well, if you feel I answered your question, I'd appreciate if you'd accept my answer!